# AWS EC2: This webpage is not available - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following this tutorial: http://amunategui.github.io/idea-to-pitch

I get everything install correct and I even changed the security groups to allow ssh from anywhere and http from anywhere. However, I am still unable to view the webpage that is supposed to say Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

Here is the ip address I am trying to connect to: http://54.187.179.134/

[image]

Comment: Check if apache is enabled or it seems that port 80 is blocked. Check the security group.

Comment: I added a picture for the security group. Where do I go to see about apache is enabled or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver is returning a HTTP 504 response - Gateway Time-out. As a result, this source of this problem isn't on the AWS level, it's on the OS level.

I haven't used Flask with Apache before, but when you get this error with NGINX, it usually means that NGINX can't talk to the WSGI daemon.

As a result, ensure your WSGI daemon is running and that Apache and WSGI are correctly configured as per the tutorial.